# Generated subselect in Hibernate - why?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, subquery

I use Hibernate and very simple Criteria API but with complex data linking.
Sometimes after loading entity I see following SQL in log:

`select * from ( select this_.ID as ID7_0_,  from AAA.CUSTOMER this_ where this_.STATUS=? and this_.ID in (select this_.ID_CUSTOMER as y0_ from AAA.CUSTOMER_CONTACT this_ where this_.ID_CONTACT in (select this_.ID as y0_ from AAA.CONTACT this_ where this_.PHONE_NUMBER=?) and this_.ROLE=?) ) where rownum <= ?`

But I don't understand why Hibernate decides to generate subselect without linking via foreign keys (they are all pointed in hbm.xml). Why there are subselects at all? I use fetch="select" or fetch="join" only.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show please entity and Critera example.

Comment: I already found out the reason of this behaviour. Thank you for participating.

Comment: The syntax is invalid (there is a `,` directly before `from AAA.CUSTOMER`). Are you sure you posted the correct statement. Btw: a JOIN and a sub-select are *not* equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The question is already non-topical. Someone made this subselect manually.